# No puedo quitar ni poner nuevos objetos a uno existente Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, mongodb

Estoy intentando actualizar una información que viene desde MongoDB, la cual me trae varios datos y que convierto a un JsonWebToken, sin embargo hay cosas que no me estan saliendo, el primero es

```
delete data.password;
```

Estoy intentando eliminar el índice password puesto que no lo necesito en el payload del JWT, sin embargo no lo elimina, aparece en la respuesta del servidor.

También estoy tratando de agregar el token al objeto `data` con esto

```
Object.assign( data, { token: token } );
data.token = token;
```

He probado las dos formas y ninguna lo añade.

Les paso el código que estoy utilizando, todo me funciona perfecto, excepto esas dos operaciones que quiero hacer.

```
    User.findOne( {}, '_id name lastname username password status' )
    .exec( ( err: NativeError, data: any ) => {
        delete data.password;
        const token = jwt.sign({ user: data }, seed, { expiresIn: 21600 });

        Object.assign( data, { token: token } );
        data.token = token;
        const update = { $push: { login_data: [ { date: new Date() } ] } };
        
        User.findByIdAndUpdate( data._id, update, () => {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Identificado correctamente',
                data
            });
        }); 
    });
```

Utilizo

> Node v10.14.0
>
> TSC  v3.1.6
>
> ES6

Esta es la respuesta del servidor ( Es development, nada comprometedor )

```
{
    "message": "Identificado correctamente",
    "data": {
        "status": "active",
        "_id": "5c760f50fd93b11d94a854c3",
        "name": "Alberto",
        "lastname": "Siurob",
        "username": "asiurob",
        "password": "$2b$10$kjhSHlqNeigZ0m81uZsO3eTl54r1lTUhcrD4Q63K5cIaTOIDpubj."
    }
}
```

Comment: Crea un objeto nuevo con los atributos: es posible que MongoDB haya marcado los atributos del objeto como *no modificables*, lo que haría que `delete` no tenga efecto.

Comment: Tuve que crear un nuevo objeto como recomendaste Pablo, tu sabes como marcar "no modificables" los objetos?

Comment: Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, mira los métodos de la clase Object de Javascript

Answer (score 0):

No se si te he entendido bien. ¿Lo que quieres es actualizar la información en mongodb?

Antes de nada, te sugeriría no trabajar con el objeto que te devuelve la petición a tu Db, si no clonarlo en una variable y trabajar sobre ésta. Podrías hacerlo así:

`let dataCloned = Object.assign({}, data);`

Respondiendo a tus dudas, creo que no te actualiza el token porque estás haciendo el update con un objeto que no tiene esa información. Lo estás añadiendo a data pero en el update le pasas la variable update.

Además, si quieres devolver el objeto sin el password, etc, deberías de trabajar sobre la respuesta de User.findByIdAndUpdate() ya que es donde devuelves el data. Aquí es donde yo me clonaría el objeto para devolver sólo las propiedades que nos interesa recuperar (o haría una búsqueda filtrando esas propiedades directamente en db ya que no las necesitas para nada más).Ç

Espero haber ayudado.

Un saludo.